# nhibernate named queries , name not found

Tags: c#, nhibernate, named

I'm coming from a Java side of using Hibernate and I just haven't found the proper place to put the named query in `NHibernate`.

Using Visual Studio 2008 , C# 2008

I have a query

```
<query name="SchwabAccountList">
  from DB_Accounts a
  where a.AdminOffCode = 'SWB'
</query>
```

and I want to put it in the `.hbm.xml` for the Account table  (`DB_Accounts`)

I put it at the end of the file but within the `<class>` tag

```
    <query name="AccountList">
      from DB_Accounts a
      where a.AdminOffCode = 'SWB'
    </query>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The code I am using, I have tried several different ways but get

`Named query not known: AccountList`

or whatever other name I tried to use  (`assembly.dir.dir.class.queryname`) that sort of thing.

The access code looks like.

```
              ISessionFactory factory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
              ISession session = factory.OpenSession();

              IList<DB_Accounts> accountList = 
                  (IList<DB_Accounts>)(session.GetNamedQuery("AccountList").List());

              foreach (BDM_Controller.Source.ORM.DB_Accounts acctRec in accountList)
              {
                         ...
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5):

I moved the query outside the  tag and got it to recognize the query. I had it at the top of the mapping file earlier and it complained about the following  tag. It might have been a problem with the single quote. I added the CDATA wrapper to protect against those issues. So a combination of the two change probably solved the problem.

I now have:

```
  </class>
  <query name="AccountList" cacheable="true" read-only="true">
    <![CDATA[
      from DB_Accounts a
      where a.AdminOffCode = 'SWB'
      ]]>
  </query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and this works

Answer (score 3):

Also, make sure that your mapping file Build Action is set as "Embedded Resource", or you'll get the same error even if the mapping file itself is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Also make sure that the hbm file is added with extension .hbm.xml rather than just .xml. This also will result in the same error.